# Android AsyncTask change

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Why, when I change

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            Downloader.DownloadFromUrl("http://www.sciencemag.org/rss/news.xml", openFileOutput("Sciencemag.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        mAdapter = new SiteAdapter(MainActivity.this, -1, XmlParser.getSingleItemsFromFile(MainActivity.this));
        sitesList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

to

```
private void downloadFile(){
    try {
        Downloader.DownloadFromUrl("http://www.sciencemag.org/rss/news.xml", openFileOutput("Sciencemag.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        mAdapter = new SiteAdapter(MainActivity.this, -1, XmlParser.getSingleItemsFromFile(MainActivity.this));
        sitesList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

i get an error? I just want to call method downloadFile() instead of creating instance of inner class DownloadTask and call execute() of this instance.

Comment: Just DON'T change it. Downloads should never done in the main thread.

Comment: Android will force you to put all network requests in a separate thread.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is telling you that you cannot make network tasks on the main thread.
Look at the Android API where [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) is defined to know more about it.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your method downloadFile() takes too long time - this will block the UI. To prevent this you should use **[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)** which will do the background operations (downloading your file i guess) and when it is ready will update your UI. In **doInBackground()** put your downloadFile() method and in **onPostExecute()** deal with the result. Also be careful what parameters to give to your **AsyncTask** class.